# Dejar + past participle

Tags: gramática, verbos, uso-de-palabras

Common sense tells me this construct should translate into something like this:

> *to leave something done.*

Which is why the following example makes complete sense to me:

> **Nos dejó preparada la cena.**
>
> *She left the dinner prepared for us.*

However, I just came across this meaning in a [SpanishDict tutorial](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/109):

> to appoint something.

The website doesn't offer any example to illustrate this interpretation and I also tried looking everywhere but couldn't find any. Could someone please explain how **dejar** could translate into *appoint* in this construct, preferably with a few examples?

Comment: Perhaps an example of "to appoint" is "dejar a cargo" (put someone in charge of something. "Maria dejó a Juan cuidando los niños"

Comment: It says appoint something, not someone. Maybe like an inheritance? Someone dies and leaves his house to his son: Dejó la casa a su hijo.

Comment: You can, for example, _dejar dicho_ or _dejar establecido_ a place or time for a meeting, as in one of the meanings of _to appoint (sth)_. Maybe that is what the translation was intended to point out with _dejar+participio_ (both dicho and establecido are participles, in fact).

Answer (score 1):

The main sense in which the English verb *to appoint* is used with a thing as object is in the sense of to nominate or arrange. The object would normally be *a time* or *a date*. So for example *The society appointed the 20th October for the next meeting*. Having said that it is a very old-fashioned formal usage. I think the sense in the DRAE of *nombrar, designar* must come close. Interestingly we do have as a current use the noun derived from the verb (*appointment*) as the thing you make with someone.